# Selenium and Iphone with pin-to-home app

Tags: iphone, selenium, appium, appium-ios

we want to test an web app on iphone. We already have a set of Selenium test. We are looking at an Appium based solution.

The app is intended to be pinned to the homescreen and started in fullscreen mode (with the header `<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">`).

Is it possible to run the selenium test in this fullscreen mode?

Answer (score 0):

Appium supports Native Apps (might be a [Hybrid App](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/web/hybrid/), yet it has to be native) and [plain Web Apps](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/web/mobile-web/#ios-mobile-web-automation) ("plain" as in "runs within Safari") only, see [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/appium-discuss/0ZhlJ-5d7PE). You might try "hacks" like scrolling Safari to auto-hide the navigation elements though.

There are, however, platforms to support homescreen apps, such as Perfecto (see [here, "Automating the PWA from Appium"](https://developers.perfectomobile.com/display/TT/Testing+Progressive+Web+App+on+iOS)):

```java
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();

// "The PWA icon display name as it is displayed on the device screen":
params.put("displayName", "mySite");

driver.executeScript("mobile:pwa:start", params);
```